# Right effort and concentration

Tags: right-effort, eightfold-path, right-intention, right-concentration

I was reading about the noble eightfold path and Right effort, thought and concentration, they seem to be very similar. What are the differences?

Answer (score 2):

Right Efforts is about removing unwholesome states and cultivating wholesome states. Right Concentration deals with developing the Jhana as a means to displace certain subset of unwholesome states. Jhana is a wholesome state hence arousing Jhana can be viewed as applying efforts to abandon the 5 hindrances. This done through developing the Jhana factors. A mind with the Jhana factors aroused is wholesome.

In short:

- Abandoning hindrances and developing the Jhanas, Right Concentration, is a subset of Right Efforts hence the similarity
- Right Effort deals with abandoning all unwholesome states and developing wholesome states, while Right Concentration deals with developing the Jahan, hence the difference

## Right Effort

> (6) And what, bhikshus, is right effort?
>   Here, bhikshus, a monk
>   brings forth the desire for the non-arising of unarisen evil unwholesome states; he makes an effort,
>   rouses energy, applies his mind, and strives;
>
> he brings forth the desire for the abandoning of arisen evil unwholesome states; he makes an effort,
>   rouses energy, applies his mind, and strives;
>
> he brings forth the desire for the arising of unarisen wholesome states; he makes an effort, rouses
>   energy, applies his mind, and strives;
>
> he brings forth the desire for the maintenance of arisen wholesome states, for their non-decay,
>   increase, growth and fulfillment by cultivation; he makes an effort, rouses energy, applies his mind, and
>   strives.
>
> This, bhikshus, is called right effort.

## Right Concentration

> And what, bhikshus, is right samadhi [concentration]?
>   Here, bhikshus,
>
> (1) a monk, detached from sensual pleasures, detached from unwholesome mental states,
>   enters and remains in the first dhyana,
>   accompanied by initial application and sustained application,
>   accompanied by zest and happiness, born of detachment [ie born of samadhi].
>
> (2) With the stilling of initial application and sustained application,
>   by gaining inner tranquillity and oneness of mind,
>   he enters and remains in the second dhyana,
>   free from initial application and sustained application,
>   accompanied by zest and happiness born of samadhi.
>
> (3) With the fading away of zest, he remains equanimous,
>   mindful and clearly knowing,
>   and experiences happiness with the body,
>   he enters and remains in the third dhyana,
>   of which the noble ones declare,
>   ‘Happily he dwells in equanimity and mindfulness.’
>
> (4) With the abandoning of pleasure and pain—
>   and with the earlier disappearance of joy and grief—
>   he enters and abides in the fourth dhyana, 
>   that is neither pleasant nor painful,
>   with a mindfulness fully purified by equanimity.
>   This, bhikshus, is called right samadhi.

[(Magga) Vibhaṅga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/14.5-Magga-Vibhanga-S-s45.8-piya.pdf) also in [Sacca Vibhanga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/11.11-Sacca-Vibhanga-S-m141-piya.pdf)